# Assign variables value through array in Haxe?

Tags: arrays, variables, haxe

How to assign variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` values to `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` through an array?

```
var a:Int = 0, b:Int = 0, c:Int = 0, d:Int = 0;
var array1:Array<Int> = [a, b, c, d];
var array2:Array<Int> = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (i in 0...4)
    array1[i] = array2[i]; //this does not work, it assigns array1's elements instead

trace(a); // this prints 0 instead of 1
trace(b); // 0 instead of 2
trace(c); // 0 instead of 3
trace(d); // 0 instead of 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that basic types like `Int` are immutable. In fact, the variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` might as well not even exist since they never change. If you look at the JS Source tab on [try.haxe.org](http://try.haxe.org/#A506E), you'll notice that they're not present in the output:

```
var array1 = [0,0,0,0];
var array2 = [1,2,3,4];
var _g = 0;
while(_g < 4) {
    var i = _g++;
    array1[i] = array2[i];
}
console.log(0);
console.log(0);
console.log(0);
console.log(0);
```

This is an optimization of the analzyer.

You'll need some sort of container type to accomplish this, like a `class` or a `typedef`. Here's an example using the latter:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var a:IntContainer = { value: 0 };
        var b:IntContainer = { value: 0 };
        var c:IntContainer = { value: 0 };
        var d:IntContainer = { value: 0 };

        var array1:Array<IntContainer> = [a, b, c, d];
        var array2:Array<Int> = [1, 2, 3, 4];

        for (i in 0...4)
            array1[i].value = array2[i];

        trace(a.value);
        trace(b.value);
        trace(c.value);
        trace(d.value);
    }
}

typedef IntContainer = {
    value:Int
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The workaround provided by @Gama11 is correct that we need a container type, but the reasoning is wrong. **The problem is not an effect of any optimization**.

If we run the JS equivalent of the code in question, we will still get the same result:

```
var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
var array1 = [a, b, c, d];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    array1[i] = array2[i];

console.log(a); // 0
console.log(b); // 0
console.log(c); // 0
console.log(d); // 0
```

In fact, this behaviour is the same in most other languages as well.

The reason is, the Array declaration takes the **values** of the input expressions instead of the **references** of them. That means `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are evaluated when setting `array1`.

This behaviour is the same for all expressions, except only for function:

```
/*
    variable
*/
var a = "A";
var b = a;
a = "B";
trace(b); // A

/*
    anon. object
*/
var a = "A";
var c = { _c: a };
a = "C";
trace(c._c); // A

/*
    Map
*/
var a = "A";
var d = ["_d" => a];
a = "D";
trace(d["_d"]); // A

/*
    function
    The function body is evaluated every time when it is called.
*/
var a = "A";
var f = function () return a;
a = "F";
trace(f()); // F <-- notice this
```

Comment: I wasn't saying that the problem is *caused* by an optimization. I added that example to underline that the variables existing or not existing doesn't make any difference to the output, as their values are not changed. Perhaps I didn't phrase that too well.